# Diffuse map bake problem?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

Not only diffuse I have the same problem with other maps as well, im not to good at interface of blender, so I might miss something somewhere, this is the screenshot.

[image: bake problem]

As you can see, some of them looks empty, and dont know why.

I usually only bake normal maps, or light shadow etc, when I need a diffuse(albedo) texture, I use texture paint and its solve cleanly. But this time I use shaders and need the outcome as a png, so I try bake the diffuse map. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Select those faces in the UV with UVsync selection enabled and look where they are... post a picture of them. Remamber that the floor object is being rendered. The eye means only viewport visibility.

Comment: well, thank you. i feel like stupid. black ones are other side of the object. Why didnt check from the beginning , i also dont know :). Thank you anyway.